# Characteristic function of product of two random variables using the conditionate expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim \mathcal{E}(2)$ and $Y_{|X=x}\sim \mathcal{E}(x)$ for all $x>0$. Find the characteristic function of $XY$ and deduce its distribution.

I tried this way:

Let

$$\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta X Y} | X)\right)$$

So, I have that, for all $x>0$:

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta X Y} | X=x)=\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta x Y} | X=x)=\varphi_{Y_{|X}}(x\theta)=\frac{x}{x-ix\theta}=\frac{1}{1-i\theta}$$

Because $\frac{1}{1-i\theta}$ is a constant, I obtain

$$\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1-i\theta}\right)=\frac{1}{1-i\theta}$$

and I conclude that $XY\sim \mathcal{E}(1)$.

Is it correct? In particular, the step where I introduce $\varphi_{Y_{|X}}$ is it right?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct to me.